# Error while creating spatial entity with Hibernate and GeometrySerializer : No qualifying bean of type 'GeometryParser<?>'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jts, hibernate-spatial

I tried to create a simple application with a geometry persistent layer (Spring boot with hibernate-spatial)

Here is my Entity class :

```java
    // Annotations from lombok project
    @NoArgsConstructor 
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data 
    @Builder
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "persistent_geometry")
    public class PersistentGeometry implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
        @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
        private UUID id;

        @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
        @JsonDeserialize(using = GeometryDeserializer.class)
        @Column(name = "geometry", columnDefinition = "geometry(Polygon,4326)")
        private Polygon geometry;

    }
```

Here is my repository interface

```java
    public interface PersistentGeometryService extends CrudRepository<PersistentGeometry, UUID> {}
```

Here is my controller class

```java
@RestController
public class PersistenGeometryController {

    @Autowired
    private PersistentGeometryService persistentGeometryService;

    @PostMapping(value="/persistentGeometry")
    public ResponseEntity createNewGeom(@RequestBody PersistentGeometry persistentGeometry) {
        PersistentGeometry newGeom = persistentGeometryService.save(persistentGeometry);
        var headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Location", "/persistentGeometry/" + newGeom.getId().toString() );
        return new ResponseEntity(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

However, when i do a POST request with this payload :

```
    {
    "geometry" : "POLYGON((<Some Coordinates here>))"
    }
```

Or its GeoJSON version :

```
        {
        "geometry" : {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[<Some Coordinates here>]]]}
    }
```

I got this error from my spring app (*com.geomdemo.peristentgeometry* is my base package name) :

> Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type,
>   class com.geomdemo.peristentgeometry.model.PersistentGeometry]]:
>
> **org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.serialization.GeometryDeserializer':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;**
>
> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: **No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.parsers.GeometryParser'**
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
>
> Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type,
>   class com.geomdemo.peristentgeometry.model.PersistentGeometry]]:
>
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: **Class
>   com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.serialization.GeometryDeserializer
>   has no default (no arg) constructor**

I found a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713934/jackson-deserialize-geojson-point-in-spring-boot) to add a `@Bean` of type  `JtsModule` so I did this :

```java
        @Configuration
        public class JacksonConfig {

            @Bean
            public JtsModule jtsModule() {
                return new JtsModule();
            }
    }
```

But it didn't help in my case....It seems clear that SPring boot is looking for a valid Beans of type GeometryParser...But How to implement such a Bean...did not found any documentation or example on how to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with a deserializer, I was missing the default no arguments constructor after I added that constructor, everything worked fine.

I see that you have the Lombok annotations, I tried with those as well, but I was getting compilation errors, but I think is because my class is `extends StdDeserializer`.

Comment: hi and thank you for your answer. I did not understand the second part of it : what is the link between Lombok  `@NoArgsConstructor` and the `extends StdDeserializer` what do you exactly suggest here ?

Comment: my suggestion would be to change the Lombok annotations and write the constructors by hand, to see if it solves the problem