# com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.JtsModule not working with springboot 2.2.4

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, jackson, deserialization, jts

I am trying to serialize/deserialize org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry(version 1.16.0) using com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.JtsModule. It comes packaged with:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.graphhopper.external</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I have registered it using spring configuration mechanism:

```
   @Bean
   public JtsModule jtsModule()
   {
      return new JtsModule();
   }
```

But somehow com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.serialization.GeometryDeserializer is not invoked.

Is there something else needed to be done?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47952637/4207306 and if you want automatic apply on all geometry object then add in objectmapper

Comment: Tried that, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

[GeometryDeserializer](https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bedatadriven/jackson/datatype/jts/serialization/GeometryDeserializer.java) / [GeometrySerializer](https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bedatadriven/jackson/datatype/jts/serialization/GeometrySerializer.java) worked for `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry`

An issue is open about it [here](https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts/issues/26)

You can create your custom serializer and deserializer for `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry` using same code available.

Example for [point](https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts/pull/18/files#diff-f892a4ba20ce0dab1c290b9f8f884bf0)

There is a PR for [Upgrade to Locationtech jts](https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts/pull/25) but not merged yet